# How to deploy angular2+ app on openShift

Tags: node.js, angular, openshift

I have created a angular app on my Windows PC. Now I want to deploy this app on Red Hat OpenShift.
I tried to searching on some of guides on internet, but actually couldn't find useful sources. Anyone used to deployed it, please give me a hand.

**Version**

OpenShift Master: v3.6.173.0.49

Kubernetes Master:
v1.6.1+5115d708d7

After many attempts I failed to deploy my app on Openshift.

but I was able deploy [this example node application](https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex)

```js
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "start": "node Server.js",
        "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod --base-href http://angular-reaction-page.paas-poc.am.lilly.com/"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "svg-pan-zoom": "^3.5.3",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.18",
        "@angular/cli": "^1.5.3",
        "express": "^4.13.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.90",
        "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
        "karma": "~1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
        "protractor": "^5.2.0",
        "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
        "tslint": "~4.5.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.1"
    }
}
```

```
Cloning "https://github.com/username/project-name.git" ...
Commit: 0964f21953324a4fc3334e2556f01650c4348d66 (adding package-lock.json)
Author: User Name - Network <email>
Date:   Thu Dec 14 15:17:04 2017 -0500
Installing application source ...
Building your Node application from source
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh
nodejs6/root/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.184.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
npm ERR!  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.184.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '151.101.184.162',
npm ERR!   port: 443,
npm ERR!   parent: '' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What service owns the IP ``151.101.184.162``? Accessing it direct there doesn't seem to be anything responding correctly on that IP.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton  I/m also not certain that means is it a connection issue?

Comment: You need to work out why that IP is being used. Looks like some package you are installing using npm is trying to pull something down from that IP.

Comment: Thanks for your response @GrahamDumpleton. I will check that..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to install angular2 app in openshift

You need to be inside your Angular application folder before running this command

```
npx nodeshift --strictSSL=false --dockerImage=bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app --imageTag=10.x --build.env OUTPUT_DIR=dist/your-angular-app-name --expose
```

It uses the openshift credentials from ~/.kube/config file

Note: npx and nodeshift are NPM modules

Nodeshift - It is used to deploy Node.js projects in openshift

Comment: @Zoe late to the party but my deployment keeps failing with 
```ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/app-root/src/package.json'```
Though I can see the file present in the archive that is upload!

Any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: @OlivierM. I edited the answer - I didn't post it. I don't use angular either. /shrug